# How efficiently handle Mssql deadlock issues in Nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, database, database-deadlocks

I am working on a project and in that project we have used MSSQL Stored Procedure with my Nodejs. When i try to make any database operation sometimes it fails because of deadlocks. I have tried using ConnectionPool but still no go.

Wanted to know a better way to handle this issue.When are using MSSQl npm 2.4 version

Comment: Are you creating connections everytime you are performing a query?

Comment: The first step to avoid deadlocks is query and index tuning so that only the rows needed by a query are touched. Application design and serializable transactions also contribute to deadlock likelihood. Add the deadlock xml to your question if you need help interpreting the diagnostic info. The deadlock xml can be retrieved with [a query of the system_health trace](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c761448b-fe66-479c-af23-e49bcecb8e75/deadlock-happen).

Comment: Check your SP for bad practices like long transactions and so on (see tips here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585374/preventing-deadlocks-in-sql-server). Check actual execution plans for each statement in that SP: look for "missing index" warnings, scans. Share SP code, execution plans, DDL and deadlock graph if you're permitted to.