# SQL Error while updating Data - Transaction (Process ID) was deadlocked

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, deadlock

Let's say my app is supposed to manage fruits. I have a bunch of rules that are supposed to detect if something is wrong with one of my fruits. Below you find the class in charge of updating the fruits detected wrong by those rules.

My problem is that since I've parallelized the process, I randomly get this error:

> Transaction (Process ID) was deadlocked on lock resources with another
>   process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim.

I don't know what's wrong with my code.

You can ask me any questions, my English is not perfect, and I've changed the name of some var (my app does not manage fruits).

```cs
public class WrongFruitBus : GenericRepository<WrongFruit>, IWrongFruitBusiness, IBaseWrong
{
    public WrongFruitBus() : base() { }
    public WrongFruitBus(ILifetimeScope _Container) : base(_Container) { }

    private readonly object currentProcessLock = new object();

    public UpdateWrongFruits {
        var CurrentProcessBus = new CurrentProcessBusiness();
        var currentProcess = new CurrentProcess();

        var FruitRulesBus = new FruitRulesBusiness(this.Container);
        var FruitViewBus = new FruitViewBusiness();

        var FruitRules = new List<FruitRule>();
        FruitRules = FruitRulesBus.GetMany(x => x.ID == entity.RulesFilterId).ToList();

        List<Task> allRules = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var fruitRule in FruitRules)
        {
            Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                using (ILifetimeScope tempContainer = this.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
                {
                    var tempWrongFruitBus = new WrongFruitBus(tempContainer);


                    //Get the request associate to the rule
                    var request = fruitRule.Request.JsonDeserialize<BaseFruitSearchSelectionModel>();

                    //Delete all existing detected fruits for this rule 
                    tempWrongFruitBus.GetManyWithSelector(x => x.ID, x => x.RulesFilterId == fruitRule.ID).ToList().ForEach(x => tempWrongFruitBus.Delete(x));

                    var searchList = FruitSearchHelper.BuildSearchRequest(request);
                    var Ids = FruitViewBus.GetCustomList(null, null, searchList, null, null);

                    var RulesLists = Ids
                        .Results
                        .Cast<FruitResult>()
                        .Select(x =>
                            new WrongFruit()
                            {
                                FruitId = x.UId,
                                RulesFilterId = FruitRule.ID,

                            }).ToList();
                    RulesLists.ForEach(x => tempWrongFruitBus.Add(x));

                    tempWrongFruitBus._BusinessUnitOfWork.Commit();

                    //Update of the process progression
                    int PercentageAdvancement = 100 / NumberOfRules;

                    lock (currentProcessLock)
                    {
                        currentProcess = CurrentProcessBus.Get(x => x.TaskName == entity.TaskName);
                        currentProcess.TaskAdvancement = currentProcess.TaskAdvancement + PercentageAdvancement;
                        if (currentProcess.TaskAdvancement > 100)
                        {
                            currentProcess.TaskAdvancement = 100;
                        }
                        CurrentProcessBus.Update(currentProcess);
                    }
                } 
            });
            allRules.Add(task);
        }
        Task.WaitAll(allRules.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Server's Log file

> UncaGS.WCF.ErrorHandler.HandleError(:0)
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump >
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest >
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump >
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process >
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.ProcessError >
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage8
>
> > System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage9
> >     System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessageCleanup
> >     System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorBehavior.HandleErrorCommon > UncaGS.WCF.ErrorHandler.HandleError
> >     System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Une exception a été levée
> >     par la cible d'un appel. --->
> >     System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error
> >     occurred while reading from the store provider's data reader. See the
> >     inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
> >     Transaction (Process ID 57) was deadlocked on lock resources with
> >     another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim.    à
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
> >     Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    à
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
> >     stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    à
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
> >     SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> >     BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> >     stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    à
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows) 
> >     à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean
> >     setTimeout, Boolean& more)    à
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()    à
> >     System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.StoreRead()
> >     --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne ---    à System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.HandleReaderException(Exception
> >     e)    à
> >     System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.StoreRead()
> >     à
> >     System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
> >     à System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
> >
> >     à System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    à
> >     UncaGS.WcfServices.Repositories.Infrastructure.ReadOnlyGenericRepositoryBase`1.GetManyWithSelector[TOutput](Int32
> >     startAt, Int32 take, Expression`1 selector, Expression`1 where,
> >     Expression`1 orderBy, Expression`1[] includeProperties)    --- Fin de
> >     la trace de la pile d'exception interne ---    à
> >     System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
> >     arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    à
> >     System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
> >     Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    à
> >     System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)    à
> >     UncaGS.WcfServices.Services.GenericService.GenericService.GenericServiceWorker.ExecuteRequest(CallMethodContractBase
> >     callMethodContract, Type repositoryType)    à
> >     UncaGS.WcfServices.Services.GenericService.GenericService.GenericServiceWorker.Execute(CallMethodContractBase
> >     callMethodContract)    à
> >     UncaGS.WcfServices.Services.GenericService.GenericService.ExecuteMethod(CallMethodContractBase
> >     callMethodContract)    à SyncInvokeExecuteMethod(Object , Object[] ,
> >     Object[] )    à
> >     System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
> >     instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    à
> >     System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
> >     rpc)    à
> >     System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
> >     rpc)    à
> >     System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
> >     rpc)    à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
> >     isOperationContextSet)

Comment: What type database are you using?  Only databases that are designed to be shared will not lock.  So using Access, Excel with give errors while using SQL Server will work.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server

Comment: Did you check the server log files to see what errors were occurring?

Comment: @jdweng Deadlocks are very common in SQL Server and are considered normal. You can never get rid of them completely, you can only make them [happen less often](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40585585/11683).

Comment: Did you read following : https://sqlbak.com/academy/transaction-process-id-was-deadlocked-on-lock-resources-with-another-process-and-has-been-chosen-as-the-deadlock-victim-msg-1205/

Comment: The SQL Server automatically performs locking when two users are simultaneously access the same data.  So you do not need to lock in the c# code.   The SQL Server is designed for multiple users and you do not need to duplicated in c# what is being performed in the Server.

Comment: I updated my post with the log file

Comment: But if I don't lock my Currentprocess I'll have concurent access to the same table no ?

Comment: @jqweng Nope I'm gonna check your link, thank you !

Comment: Using the deadlock log file from SQL Server Manager, the problem seems to be when I delete the existing fruits for the rule. There is a conflict betweem two process one trying to execute a Select and another trying to execute Delete, but I dont understant why ...

Comment: An easy fix here would be to accumulate the results of the rule evaluation in a single  collection, say a `ConcurrentBag<WrongFruit>`, and then perform all the deletes after the parallel rule processing.